# How to get all images uploaded by the user?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-rest-api

Using Twitter API, I would like to fetch all images uploaded by a user who authenticated my application (OAuth). I've been digging API docs but couldn't find an easy way to do it.

Should I list all tweets, iterate over them, get every single tweet and see if it has a media entity? C'mon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific media fetching endpoint in the Twitter API, so yes, you'd need to do something along those lines.

- call the `statuses/user_timeline.json` endpoint and page through it (supports up to 3200 Tweets). I'd suggest using the `?tweet_mode=extended` parameter, to ensure you get media entities for any longer Tweets
- iterate through the Tweet objects, looking for any `extended_entities` objects (these contain images or videos)
- grab the images from the URL inside the object